# Android encryption large files

Tags: android, encryption

I try encrypt and decrypt large audio binary files. With using CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream. I know, about existing many questions about theme like this. But I can't understand what's wrong with my code. Please describe clearly what wrong. Thanks.

```
public void encrypt() {
    doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEY);
}

public void decrypt() {
    doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, KEY);
}

private void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key) {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(this);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(this);

        int read;

        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher);

        while ((read = cis.read()) != -1) {
            cos.write(read);
            cos.flush();
        }
        cos.close();
        cis.close();

        inputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException
            | InvalidKeyException | IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error encrypting/decrypting file at .hortext.HortextFile.doCrypto(HortextFile.java:81)
     at .tools.hortext.HortextFile.decrypt(HortextFile.java:52)
     at .tools.hortext.FilesStorage.getStringFromStorage(FilesStorage.java:104)
     at com.msg.mobilinga.ui.ListenTextActivity.onCreate(ListenTextActivity.java:83)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while finalizing cipher
     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.fillBuffer(CipherInputStream.java:104)
     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:130)
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.HortextFile.doCrypto(HortextFile.java:69)
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.HortextFile.decrypt(HortextFile.java:52) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.FilesStorage.getStringFromStorage(FilesStorage.java:104) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.ui.ListenTextActivity.onCreate(ListenTextActivity.java:83) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
  Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:894)
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1314)
     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.fillBuffer(CipherInputStream.java:102)
     at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:130) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.HortextFile.doCrypto(HortextFile.java:69) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.HortextFile.decrypt(HortextFile.java:52) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.tools.hortext.FilesStorage.getStringFromStorage(FilesStorage.java:104) 
     at com.msg.mobilinga.ui.ListenTextActivity.onCreate(ListenTextActivity.java:83) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. My exception is not visible by editor. I'm edited post. Please get out your minus. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine apart from reading and writing byte by byte, using ECB mode and using an text encoded key. Scratch that ... why are you using `CipherInputStream` *and* `CipherOutputStream` at the same time?

Comment: @ArtjomB. hmm, Can you told me how I must to do ? Thanks.

Comment: @ArtjomB. One stream reading for encoding decoding, other write the same file with results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is very likely:

```
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher);
```

You should only use one of them. A `Cipher` holds some state, but since you're passing the `cipher` to both streams they will both use the same state and unpredictable stuff will happen (technical term :)).

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

int read;

CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);

while ((read = cis.read()) != -1) {
    fileOutputStream.write(read);
}
fileOutputStream.close();
cis.close();
```

Of course, it will be much more performant if you use a buffer:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

int read;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);

while ((read = cis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
fileOutputStream.close();
cis.close();
```

Keep in mind that you cannot write to a file you're currently reading from. You have to use two files.

---

Security considerations:

- Always use a fully qualified cipher string. `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` will select some cipher depending on defaults which will most likely be `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");`. Default may change which will break your code.
- Never use ECB mode, because it's not [semantically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).
- CBC mode provides semantic security, but only with an unpredictable (read random) IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can just prepend it to the ciphertext and slice off before decryption.
- Authenticating your ciphertexts prevents many attacks. You can either use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or apply an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html) scheme with a strong MAC function like HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: You answer is really beauty. This planet must have more guys like you. But I have different problem, result file is empty.

Comment: I don't know what `this` is in your code, but I suspect you created a subclass for `File`. In that case, you cannot write to a file you're currently reading to.

Comment: yeah, you right about subclass of File. You mean my code only reading, and not write into file ?

Comment: Thanks ..........

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) is why you should not use ECB mode.

(An answer for the image)

[image]

(image [linked from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), see abovr URL)

Comment: what need use to do secure binary file ?

Comment: You need to use CBC mode.